# Detect person in bed

Tags: computer-vision

Suppose I want to find out if there is a person in a bed or not using cameras and computer vision algorithms. One can assume that the camera provides RGB, infrared and depth data.

I don't really have a good idea how to solve this. So far I came up with this:

1. Estimate a plane using RANSAC of the bed object. This plane should be further away from the ground plane, if there is a person in the bed. This seems very unstable though, assumes that the normal height of a bed is known and can easily be broken if the bed has an adjustable head part (e.g. in a hospital)
2. Face detection. Try to detect a face in the bed. Probably also isn't very reliable since the face can be sideways to the camera and partly covered.
3. Use the infrared-image. I am not sure how much you would see through the blanket and what would happen if the person just left the bed and the bed is still warm?

Is there a good way to do this? Or, to be reliable, you would have to use pressure sensors in the bed?

Thanks!

Comment: I would place the camera directly over the bed (attached to the ceiling) and apply people detection algorithms.

Comment: hmm..i am afraid that is probably not an option for me. I need to see more of the room with the camera than just the bed. But I'd be interested how well this would work...

Comment: Can you upload few sample images.. also is your camera position is fixed or it can be anywhere in the room?

Answer (score 3):

I dont know about infrared images but for camera based video processing this kind of problem is widely studied.

If your problem is to detect a person in a bed which is "Normally empty" then I think the simplest algorithm would be to capture successive frames and calculate their difference.
The existence of human in the frame would make it different from a frame capturing only empty bed. Depending on various algorithms like [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5223320) you would get different reliability.

Otherwise you can go directly for human detection in video frames. One possible [algorithm](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1467360) is described here.

**Edit:**

Your problem is harder than i thought. The following approach might solve the cases.
The main idea is to use bunch of features at once to get higher accuracy and remove false positives.

1. Use HOG person detector at top level to detect a person's entry in the scene. If the position of the possible entry doors are known or detectable using edge lines in the scene use it to increase accuracy. (At the point of entry the diference in successive frames will be located near the doors)
2. Use Edge lines to track the human. And use the bed edges to track the position of the human. The edges of human should be bounded by the edges of the bed.
3. If the difference is located within the bed implies human is in the bed but moving.
4. If needed as a preprocessing step include analysis of texture, connected component to remove possible moving objects in the room for higher accuracy (for example:- movement of clothes because of air).
5. Also use face detectors to increase accuracy.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know the HOG person detector, but was doubtful if it was suitable for detecting persons lying in a bed. All pedestrian detectors I have heard of so far concentrate on people walking around. About the image differences: This also does not seem very reliable. If a person moves strongly in a bed, consecutive frames would like very different even though there was always a person in bed.

Comment: I am just curious. Can you share what exactly is your application and some sample images of room!! It might be helpfull to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Infrared that camera uses has a different frequency than infrared signal from a warm object. Unless you are using military grade IR scanners you can forget about connection IR-warmth. But IR is still useful if there is limited light or you use it for depth maps.

Go with depth (Kinect style) and estimate bed as a segment at your image. It should have some features in depth (certain dimension, flatness, etc). The bed usually surrounded by walls or floor that are easy to segment out. You algorithm can also be tuned to the distance to the bed and cut it out based just on depth range.

As other people said, it will be useful to learn more about your particular goal or application. What is background or environment around the bed? how does it looks when there is no person in it? Can a person simulate his/her presence(as in prison escape scenario), etc. etc.